# Can anyone help me identify the issue with the save function and guide me on how to resolve it?

Tags: php, laravel

### Context

I am working on a Laravel application where I have implemented a Livewire component for creating and saving posts. However, I am facing issues with the save function not working as expected. Below are the relevant code snippets for the Blade file, Livewire component, and Post model.

### Issue

The issue I am facing is that the daftar method in the Livewire component is not being triggered when I click the Submit button, and the form data is not being saved to the database. I have ensured that the Livewire component is correctly defined, bound to the form, and handles the form submission, but the save function is not working as expected.

### Code

##### Blade File

This is the Blade file where I have a form to input the title and description of a post and button to submit the form.

```
<x-app-layout>
<div>
    <x-input type="text" id="title" name="title" wire:model="title"/>
    <x-input type="text" id="description" name="description" wire:model="description"/>
    <x-button wire:click="daftar()" type="button">Submit</x-button>
</div>
</x-app-layout>
```

##### Livewire Component File

This is the Livewire component file where I have defined the PostForm component with a daftar method to handle the form submission and save the post data to the database.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Post\Form;

use App\Models\Post;
use Livewire\Component;

class PostForm extends Component
{
    public $title;
    public $description;

    public function daftar()
    {
        $this->validate([
            'title' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'description' => 'required|string',
        ]);

        $post = new Post();
        $post->title = $this->title;
        $post->description = $this->description;
        $post->user_id = auth()->id();
        $post->save();

        session()->flash('success', 'Post successfully added.');
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.post-form');
    }
}
```

##### Model File

This is the model file for the Post model where I have defined the model with the $fillable property to specify which model attributes can be mass assigned.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'description',
        'user_id',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using this <button wire:click="daftar" type="button">Submit</button>
    Just so we can make sure where the error is

Comment: I already did that remove the bracket nothing happens and if i replace with form it show the result on the search bar title = ... & description= ....

Comment: I already did that remove the bracket nothing happens and if i replace with form it show the result on the search bar title = ... & description= ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to actually save the records in the database I believe the submit action should happen in the form attribute like the following:

`<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" wire:submit="save">`

After you do that, I would do a dd() of the validated records before saving them just to see if it is hitting the method and passing the validation

Also, if you are saving the records, I would stick to the naming convention and change the name from "daftar" to "save".